# Bad Request when Post Json Data from Android to API MVC

Tags: android, asp.net-mvc

i don't understand,i have three item,first item i post json to updated with status code is 200,but from second item, i received status code 400 bad request.i try use Post Man to test it then received status code is 200 for all item.

this is my code in android:

```
protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpResponse response;
        String responseString = null;
        try {
            HttpPost post = new HttpPost(UrlRequest);
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            String jsonData = gson.toJson(_saleModel);                
            StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(jsonData);
            entity.setContentType("application/json");
            post.addHeader("Authorization", "bearer ".concat(mSession.getAccessToken()));
            post.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
            post.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=utf-8");
            post.setEntity(entity);
            response = httpclient.execute(post);
            StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
            if(statusLine.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK){
                ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                response.getEntity().writeTo(out);
                responseString = out.toString();
                out.close();
            } else{
                //Closes the connection.
                response.getEntity().getContent().close();
                throw new IOException(statusLine.getReasonPhrase());
            }
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            //TODO Handle problems..
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            //TODO Handle problems..
            Log.e("Error",e.getMessage());
        }

        return responseString;
    }
```

and this is in API MVC:

```
[HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage UpdateSale(SalesModel sale)
    {
        var result = new JObject();
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, new { success = false, message = ModelState});
        try
        {
            var isAdded = _saleService.UpdateSale(sale);
            if (!isAdded.HasErrors)
            {
                result = JObject.FromObject(new { success = true, message = "Cập nhật thành công!" });
            }
            else
            {
                result = JObject.FromObject(new { success = false, message = isAdded.Errors });
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, ex.Message);
        }

        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, result);
    }
```

Please help me!i'm sorry about my english!

Comment: please retrofit2 is awesome

Comment: The 400 Bad Request error is an HTTP status code that means that the request you sent to the website server, often something simple like a request to load a web page, was somehow incorrect or corrupted and the server couldn't understand

Comment: thanks!but i don't understand HTTP status code is 200 for first item,from second item is HTTP status code 400,i try using Post Man to test my api then i received HTTP status code 200,are you any idea?

Comment: show how you use call each item

Comment: here,i get data from view and set to my model with name: "_saleModel".I have a list,when i click on each item,this will show actitvity to update each item and have button to save what i changed

private void setDataToModel(){
        _saleModel.setTitle(etTitle.getText().toString());
        _saleModel.setStartDate(etStartDate.getText().toString());
        _saleModel.setEndDate(etEndDate.getText().toString());
        _saleModel.setContent(etContent.getText().toString());
    }